# How can I assign a value to a variable int the method signature of a view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Here is the view method in the controller class:

```
        public ViewResult Show(int id)
        {
            ShowViewModel showView = new ShowViewModel();
            showView.Show = _Repository.GetById(id);

            ViewBag.title = showView.Show.collectionName;
            return View(showView);
        }
```

And here is the GetByID() method:

```
        public PodcastShow GetPodcastById(int Id)
        {
            foreach(var show in podcasts)
            {
                if(show.NameRoute == podId)
                {
                    return show;
                }
            }
            return podcasts.FirstOrDefault();
        }
```

I need to assign a value to the "int ID" variable, so I can use the specific object data to create the Show view.

Thanks in advance!

Here is the Home view:

```
@model PodcastListViewmodel;

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.title</title>
</head>
<body>
    @foreach (var podcast in Model.Podcasts)
    {

                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <a href="./podcast/show/@podcast.NameRoute">
                        <img src="@podcast.ImageUrl" width="200" height="200" />
                    </a>
                </div>

    }
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the show view, that i am trying to create with the data that the user selects:

```
@model ShowViewModel

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="@Model.Show.artworkUrl600" width="200" height="200"/>
    <h2>@Model.Show.collectionName</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

PodcastShow class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PodCast.Models
{
    public class PodcastShow
    {
        public int collectionId { get; set; }
        public string collectionName { get; set; }
        public string artworkUrl600 { get; set; }
        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
        public string releaseDate { get; set; }
        public string feedUrl { get; set; }
        public string NameRoute { get; set; }
        public List<PodcastEpisode> Episodes { get; set; }


    }
}
```

Comment: your question is not quite clear

Comment: So i have a home page that is an IEnumerable of objects. When the user clicks on one object, I want to create a view using the data from the object that is selected

Comment: and what's stopping you from doing that ?

Comment: I'm really not sure how to go about it.

Comment: you need to show your view specific code

Comment: Could you also show us your PodcastShow class and table scheme in the database?

Comment: Here is the home view

Comment: I don't have a database setup yet. All the objects are coming in as JSON and being parsed at runtime

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public ViewResult Show(string id)
{
     ShowViewModel showView = new ShowViewModel();
     showView.Show = _Repository.GetPodcastById(id);

     ViewBag.title = showView.Show.collectionName;
     return View(showView);
}

public PodcastShow GetPodcastById(string Id) 
{ 
    return podcasts.Single(x => x.NameRoute == Id); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not quite clear what your entities look like, but I think you need something like this:

```
public PodcastShow GetPodcastById(int Id)
{
    return podcasts.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.NameRoute==Id);
}
```

Given that NameRoute is the Id you're looking for.

Comment: I gave that a shot, but ran into the same error. because the int Id variable isn't being assigned, when it tries to run the GetPodcastById method, it doesn't match with any values in the list